# How to increase the 2d collider size for animated object in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, sprite, collider

I have an animation object in shape of ball with different sizes. Think of it like a ball that increase in size from small to large but during the entire animation I want the size of the collider to remain constant through out the animation or always equal to the biggest sprite. How would I do that?

Thanks,

Comment: **Don't** ask more than one question in a question. Click edit to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To make sure that collider stays same size, make it a parent object to sprite. Sprite will be its child and this what you will be animating (making it bigger).

[image]

2. To display always in landscape mode, go to File -> Build Settings -> Resolution and Presentation -> Orientation

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Why didn't I think of parenting before.